# GoogleMaps Platform - Places API - Wider search area

Tags: python

Is there a way using Google Maps 'Places API' to run query that returns locations beyond a radius limit of 40000 meters? A much wider search area?

I'd really like to do a query where search location is a 'State' such as "Alabama", "Georgia", etc. Ex.

"Return all the McDonald's in the State of Georgia."

I'm using Python.

I'd like to search by 'state'

Comment: Please post some code your working with, since your using python. Show a good faith effort that you made an attempt on this issue. Also if your only question is whether it's possible, also ask whether you'll be satisfied with a yes or no answer. If not, maybe reform your question to something more specific.